# Magento2 currency switcher using rest API for mobile app

Tags: magento2, rest-api, multicurrency

I am creating a Magento website with currency switcher, It works fine in webview. I need the same for mobile app. If the user changed the currency once, all the prices should change to selected currency.

Is there any default API for this functionality?

Comment: check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286033/magento2-currency-switcher-using-rest-api-for-mobile-app